# Can't change label text in Xamarin forms code behind

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm a beginner of Xamarin Forms. I add label and button control with C# code. I hope click button and it can change label text at the same time on app. But it can't now.
Part of my code as below.

```
 Label lblPanel = new Label ();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Grid grid = new Grid()
        {
            RowSpacing = 10,
            ColumnSpacing = 10
        };
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { });

        Label lblPanel = new Label { Text = "0", FontSize = 50, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End };
        grid.Children.Add(lblPanel, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(lblPanel, 4);
        Grid.SetRow(lblPanel, 0);

        var btn01 = new Button { Text = "1", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn01.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn01, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn01, 4);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn01, 2);

        var btn02 = new Button { Text = "2", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn02.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn02, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn02, 4);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn02, 1);

        var btn03 = new Button { Text = "3", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn03.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn03, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn03, 4);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn03, 0);

        var btn04 = new Button { Text = "4", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn04.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn04, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn04, 3);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn04, 2);

        var btn05 = new Button { Text = "5", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn05.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn05, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn05, 3);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn05, 1);

        var btn06 = new Button { Text = "6", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn06.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn06, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn06, 3);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn06, 0);

        var btn07 = new Button { Text = "7", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn07.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn07, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn07, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn07, 2);

        var btn08 = new Button { Text = "8", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn08.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn08, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn08, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn08, 1);

        var btn09 = new Button { Text = "9", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn09.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn09, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn09, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn09, 0);

        var btn0 = new Button { Text = "0", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btn0.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btn0, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(btn0, 3);
        Grid.SetRow(btn0, 5);

        var btnClear = new Button { Text = "C", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btnClear.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Clear_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btnClear, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(btnClear, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(btnClear, 3);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnClear, 3);

        var btnEqual = new Button { Text = "=", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btnEqual.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Caculate_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btnEqual, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btnEqual, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnEqual, 3);

        var btnDivision = new Button { Text = "/", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btnDivision.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Caculate_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btnDivision, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btnDivision, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnDivision, 0);

        var btnTimes = new Button { Text = "*", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btnTimes.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Caculate_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btnTimes, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btnTimes, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnTimes, 1);

        var btnCut = new Button { Text = "-", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btnCut.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Caculate_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btnCut, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btnCut, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnCut, 2);

        var btnPlus = new Button { Text = "+", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btnPlus.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Caculate_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btnPlus, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btnPlus, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnPlus, 3);

        var btnDot = new Button { Text = ".", BackgroundColor = Color.CadetBlue };
        btnDot.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            BtnNumber_Click(sender, e);
        };
        grid.Children.Add(btnDot, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(btnDot, 5);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnDot, 3);

        Content = grid;      
    }
```

And button click event.

```
    private void BtnNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var numButton = (sender as Button);
        var keyInNumber = numButton.Text;
        if (lblPanel.Text == "0")
            lblPanel.Text = keyInNumber;
        else
            lblPanel.Text += keyInNumber;
    }
```

I can see lblPanel.text was changed in debug mode but it isn't changed on app.  Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: How many times do you want to change text of lblPanel? It would change only once from 0 to 1 at first click.

Comment: sorry, I fixed my code. I want to change label.text when I press button every time, but now, it doesn't change text  from 0 to 1 even.

Comment: Do you need increment 1  by 1 every time you click button? What exactly you need can you please tell us.

Comment: Your keyInNumber is set to numButton.Text yet numButton.Text is never changed.

Your button text is initially set to 1. So once your click event fires lbl.Panel goes from 0 to 1. But your keyInNumber value will never change i.e. it will remain 1.

So your lblPanel.Text will be 111111.....

Comment: Hi, Arvindraja. I updated entire code. I want to implement a simple caculator. lblPanel is show current input number or sign , ex: 1+1, but now , i click any number button, the lblPanel alway show 0. what's the problem with my code? Thanks all!

Comment: Hi, Jan Andersen. I tried your advice. It doesn't work... I checked the  lblPanel.Text in debug mode, it was changed by my click function but nothing happend on apps. Should I use data binding method? But I don't know how to implement data binding in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define lblPanel twice, inside and outside the constructor, which makes the inner one local to the MainPage, while BtnNumber_Click works on the global one...

It should be like

```
public Label lblPanel; // <-- here you define it..
public MainPage() {
   ...
   // Here you assign it..
   lblPanel = new Label { Text = "0",...
```